# b43-fwcutter install fails. No internet access

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, broadcom

I am trying to get my wifi or ethernet connection to work on Ubuntu 10.04.  Neither will. I therefor have no internet access. There seems to be driver issue.

From what I've seen, the first step to resolving this is to install b43-fwcutter.  Multiple sources state this, including the "official docs" about such.

Here's the problem - when I attempt this installation it fails because it apparently requires internet access!  It uses wget in it's process.  Why?  How do I skip that?  It's trying to get the file `wl_apsta-3.130.20.0.o` from a remote source.  I have that file locally.  I thought that am supposed to install that with b43-fwcutter AFTER b43-fwcutter is installed first?

COMMAND:

```
sudo dpkg -i /media/UBUNTUSB/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/*
```

RESULT:

```
(Reading database ... 122496 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace b43-fwcutter 1:012-1build1 (using .../b43-fwcutter_012-1build1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement b43-fwcutter ...
Setting up b43-fwcutter (1:012-1build1) ...
--2017-03-29 10:43:33--  http://downloads.openwrt.org/sources/wl_apsta-3.130.20.0.o
Resolving downloads.openwrt.org... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `downloads.openwrt.org'
dpkg: error processing b43-fwcutter (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 4
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 b43-fwcutter
```

*BTW: I'm pretty sure firmware-b43-installer is not an option on Ubuntu v10.

Comment: I'm pretty sure firmware-b43-installer is not an option on Ubuntu v10.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong about that!

Comment: I don't know. 10.04 is off-topic anyway. But it may install the firmware.

Comment: What do you mean 10.04 is "off-topic"?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 is EoL and off-topic at this site. The answer I gave a link to tells how to use b43-fwcutter manually.

Comment: I would not have this problem if I were using a newer version of Ubuntu.  That's the cause of the driver issue AND the reason I'm asking here b/c there is no documentation I can find about this v.

Comment: I already am installing b43-fwcutter "manually", ie. from a local source, as can be seen in my post.

Comment: This question will be closed soon as off-topic. We do not support 10.04 here. You can ask at [linux.se], or Ubuntu forums.

Comment: Great.  That makes a hell of a lot of sense...  One can't ask questions about that which is hard to find answers?

Comment: Please see the duplicate answer. You can easily install the firmware offline. As soon as you get the wireless working, please upgrade to *at least* 14.04 LTS. We have made a lot of progress in drivers, Network Manager, etc., since 2010!

Comment: Thank you, but I can't!  I have Ubuntu 16.  It does me no good I must use v10 for a specific and complicated matter involving compiling an Android Gingerbread ROM from source.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the file manager to dig into the deb file and pull out the b43-fwcutter binary.  That's the file you want. It's in the data.tar.xz  usr/bin directory in the deb.

---

Your posted example was trying to install the .deb file, not running the executable.  What error did the executable give and what driver file did you give it?

Not all firmware versions are supported by b43-fwcutter.  Run it on the driver file you have (the windows driver bcmlw.sys file for example with the -i switch to identify what version your driver is.  Then run the b43-f2cutter with the -l switch to see what versions are supported.

Comment: Thanks.  I do not have a problem finding b43-fwcutter.  I am running it.  It fails.

Comment: Excellent suggestion!  Thanks for your help @ubfan1.  I'm glad not everyone ignores me because a program from 2010 is too "ancient", and therefor not something I can ask questions about (when I absolutely must use it).

Comment: The solution was actually a bit more simple, though.  See my answer.

Comment: I can't post the "answer" because the question has been "closed". So here's what happened.  When you try to install b43-fwcutter for the FIRST TIME, a menu screen appears which says that it needs to install firmware that it can't be package with.  Then it asks Y/N proceed. Clicking yes leads to this wget deal.  I wasn't paying close enough attention clearly.  Then, it never shows that menu again when you try to reinstall.  It simply appears to fail.  It DOES, however, install despite this error displayed during that process!